# CoreData: Dealing with polymorphic associations?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, database-design, core-data

I'm not sure if I'm using the correct term here, but let's say I have four entities in my model: `Person`, `Place`, `Tag`, and `Photo`. Any of the other three entities can have a `Photo` related to it. Sometimes a `Person` will have taken the photo and will attach it to a `Tag`, or a `Place`, or even another `Person`. What is the best way to approach polymorphic associations in CoreData?

Comment: You need to look at relationships.

Comment: What do you mean look at relationships?

Comment: Person, Place and Tag may all have a (many to many) relationship with your Photo entity. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html

Comment: The inverse relationships would get messy if doing it that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not recommend entity inheritance for something as simple as this.  For this design you have three relationships, each of the `Person`, `Place` and `Tag` have a relationship to `Photo.`Photo` has three inverse relationships.  It does not need to be any more complicated than that.

Entity inheritance is a very delicate tool that can easily cause you many problems.  Any entities that inherit from another will be flattened into a single table.  If, as @morningstar suggested you created a `Noun` entity and have `Person`, `Place` and `Tag` inherit from it you will have **ONE** table in the SQLite file with indexes pointing to itself and other nastiness.

### When to use entity inheritence?

That is a rather hard question to answer with a simple rule.  However, I would say that a baseline would be to make sure that the resulting table has at least a 70% fill.  For example, if you have an abstract with 6 attributes and two children with 2 attributes then that would probably be about an 80% fill rate and potentially ok.

In general, I do not use entity inheritence as it has little benefit and a great deal of risk to performance.  The old rule works, don't use it unless you know you *need* to use it.

Comment: Ok, what if I am doing something more complicated? Say I have `Save`, `Email`, and `Tag`, all inheriting from the same abstract entity. Is there a way to have inheritance from abstract entities in such a way that it does NOT flatten it into one table? Because basically I want to be sharing certain attributes among the three entities `Save`, `Email`, and `Tag`, such as all of them having a `uid` number. Would it be better to just make three separate entities or to inherit from an abstract entity?

Comment: It is nearly always (read "always") to create them as separate entities.  This is not a database and data normalization is actually a bad thing.  In your case described above I would definitely keep them separate.

Comment: I think you made a typo, but did you mean to say "nearly always... better"?

Comment: Also, when is an appropriate time to use abstract entities then?

Answer (score 0):

Another way of dealing with this is to create subclasses of Photo, each with their own set of relationships. So, you'd create PersonPhoto, PlacePhoto, and TagPhoto. Each of these entities would have the appropriate relationship with Person, Place, and Tag, respectively. All of the common functionality and attributes would live in Photo, but the subclasses keep the relationships separated.

This is probably equivalent to creating all of these relationships on Photo, but I think it's a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @mzarra.  If you have `Person`, `Place` and `Tag` have a relationship to `Photo` it will be way easier to manage, and you avoid the flattened table indexing issues.  Use other design pattern to abstract the common behaviors between `Person`, `Place` and `Tag`.  On the storage side, you end up with some extra unused space on `Photo` for the inverse relationships you are not using, but it balances the wasted storage you would have on entity inheritance storing the class for each entry on the table.

Answer (score -1):

Use entity inheritance. Make a parent entity of Person, Place, and Tag. In this case the parent entity is pretty stupid. It has no attributes. It doesn't represent any clear category of objects. Call it "Noun" is the best I can come up with.

It has a to-many relationship photos to type Photo. Photo has the inverse relationship isPhotoOf with type Noun.

Comment: Thank you for that. I had an inkling somewhere in my notes that I should be using inheritance, but totally forgot about it while approaching this particular problem. Do you think an abstract entity would be appropriate in this situation?

Comment: Do *not* use entity inheritance for this.  Entity inheritance will flatten your model in SQLite and put everything in one table.

Comment: Don't use entity inheritance, as mentioned above